# How to change background on UICollectionview cells swift

Tags: ios, swift, background, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an app with a text field in one view controller and a collection view in the other. I am displaying the text that is typed in the collection view cells. this works great however I have hard coded two cells which I want to display above the user entered text. I want to change the background on just those two cells is this possible?
"NAMES" and "Scores" are the hard coded items (the ones I want to change the background on) thanks for any help

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return ScoreArray.count     
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let Cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let Mycell = Cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

    Mycell.text = ScoreArray[indexPath.row]

    return Cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ScoreArray.append("NAMES")
    ScoreArray.append("SCORES")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of tableView we get a contentView added by default. For collectionView we can access it too using code Eg:

```
let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCellID", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
myCell.contentView.backgroundColor = .gray // contentView is  get only
myCell.contentView.addSubView(UIView())
```

Comment: What does adding UIView() as subView do? This seems convoluted.

Comment: Your question is confusing for me what does changing background means..changing the color, view or show anything?

Answer (score 0):

To change the background **color** of your cell to, say, green:

```
Cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
```

To change a specific cell, you need to look at the indexPath, because the indexPath is what uniquely identifies a cell.

indexPath has section and row properties. Assuming you have only one section, you can just look at the row property in `cellForItemAt`, like this:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    // make the first cell green
    Cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
else {
    // make all others red
    Cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: but how do I chose a specific cell to change the color of?